# pyspark dataframe iterate over the list

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list and pyspark dataframe like below. Today my list has only 3 elements and tomorrow it might have 5 elements and the list is dynamic not static.

```
         my_list = ['4587','9920408','9920316']

         a=spark.createDataFrame([(101,'~1~20448~3~22901~12214~27681~9920408~20013~19957~19993~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~'),(102, '~1~20448~4462~4586~24739~4587~9914381~9921471~12777~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~'),(103,'~1~20448~3~22901~3891~4148~9920948~14845~4230~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~'),(104, '~1~20448~3~22901~3891~4148~9920316~4211~4212~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~')], ['ID', 'MSH'])
```

Now i want to create with column like ind if msh like '%~4587~%' or msh like '%~9920408~%' or msh like '%~9920316~%' then it's 1 otherwise 0.

I tried like below and it's working.

```
   b=a.withColumn('ind', F.expr("if((msh like '%~4587~%' or msh like '%~9920408~%' or msh like '%~9920316~%'),1,0)"))
```

Is there a way to have a dynamically create the if condition to have msh like n times if we have n items in the list.

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple likes should consider using `rlike` regular matching, and use `|` to match multiple patterns at the same time.

```
reg_expr = '|'.join([f'~{i}~' for i in my_list])
b = a.withColumn('ind', F.expr(fr"if(msh rlike '{reg_expr}', 1, 0)"))
b.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7.15. Getting syntax error as below.                                            
   reg_expr = '|'.join([f'~{i}~' for i in my_list])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    reg_expr = '|'.join([f'~{i}~' for i in my_list])
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Try: `reg_expr = '|'.join(['~{}~'.format(i) for i in my_list])`

Comment: Thank you for that. Getting error for the next statement  -                                      
 b = a.withColumn('ind', F.expr(fr"if(msh rlike '{reg_expr}', 1, 0)"))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    b = a.withColumn('ind', F.expr(fr"if(msh rlike '{reg_expr}', 1, 0)"))
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: In the same principle, the `f` format mode is switched to the `format` format mode.

Comment: we have fr here but not f. So not sure how to make it work. Appreciate your support.

Comment: `b = a.withColumn('ind', F.expr(r"if(msh rlike '{}', 1, 0)".format(reg_expr)))`

Comment: thank you so much for your prompt reply. It worked for me in python 2.